# Обновление процента загрузки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возникла задача написать обновления процента загрузки. Как это можно сделать на `python3`?
нужно обновлять текст в терминале через несколько секунд.

Comment: @Ukeo, каждый раз новая строка. нужно обновить текущую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Text Progress Bar in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console)

```
for i in range(100):
  time.sleep(1)
  sys.stdout.write("\r%d%%" %i)    # or print >> sys.stdout, "\r%d%%" %i,
  sys.stdout.flush()
```